# relationship between tables hsqldb

Tags: database, relationship, hsqldb, foreign-key-relationship

I need to create two tables in relationship one to many. I have created following statements. Maven gives me an error about "unique constraint". I don't know how to fix it, someone can explain me how to create correct relationship in this example?

```
CREATE TABLE Owner(
owner_id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, 
firstname varchar(20), 
lastname varchar(20)
)
"CREATE TABLE Picture(
picture_id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, 
owner_id INT, name varchar(20), 
width INT, height INT, 
FOREIGN KEY(pic_owner_id) REFERENCES Owner(owner_id)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a primary key.

CREATE TABLE Owner(
owner_id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
firstname varchar(20), 
lastname varchar(20)
)